# How to set "toggle-spacing" style property to GtkMenuItem in gtk+?

Tags: gtk

How can I set "toggle-spacing" style property to GtkMenuItem in gtk+?

I have added five GtkImageMenuItem(gtk_image_menu_item_new_with_label) to GtkMenu. Now I want to provide spacing between Image and label of this  GtkImageMenuItem.

There is a style property (toggle-spacing) in GtkMenuItem to provide spacing between image and label.
How can I use this property?

I want to give alternate colors to each GtkMenuItem. How it is possible?
Kinda menu I want to create is shown in this image.

[image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4030/4463974703_2350ee57da_o.jpg))</sub>

Thanks,
KBalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setting Properties.](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-properties.html)

To make the row colors alternate use [gtk_tree_view_set_rules_hint](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-rules-hint).